# Quantity extension in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

How do I properly use the [PQ-translation](http://hl7.org/fhir/R4/extension-iso21090-pq-translation.html) extension in a MedicationDispense quantity element?

I have tried the following, but I get an error **'Parser: The 'quantity' and '_quantity' properties cannot both contain complex data. (at line 10, 18)'**.

```
{
    "resourceType": "MedicationDispense",
    "status": "completed",
    "quantity": {
        "value": "14",
        "code": "767525000",
        "unit": "eenheid",
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct"
    },
    "_quantity": {
      "extension": [
        {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/iso21090-PQ-translation",
          "valueQuantity": {
            "value": "14000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use only one of them? `quantity` or `_quantity`

By checking some examples and the documentation only one of them should be used.

Try like this:

```
{
    "resourceType": "MedicationDispense",
    "status": "completed",
    "quantity": {
        "value": "14",
        "code": "767525000",
        "unit": "eenheid",
        "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/iso21090-PQ-translation",
            "valueQuantity": {
              "value": "14000"
            }
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

Some links which use **MedicationDispense**:

https://jpfhir.jp/jpcorev1ig/StructureDefinition-JP-MedicationDispense-Injection-mappings.html
https://simplifier.net/guide/SwedishNationalMedicationList/MedicationDispenseNLLDispensePaperPrescription?version=current

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Using an '_' element name is only for simple types (string, integer, etc.).  For complex types like Quantity, extensions are sent inline.

@juanmjmjr has the correct syntax.

Comment: I didn't realize the distinction; thanks very much!